# SQL statement over three tables is too slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT 
    table1.[col1],
    table1.[col2],
    table1.[col3],
    table1.[col4], 
    SUM(table3.[col5]), 
    SUM(table3.[col6]), 
    SUM(table3.[col7]) 
FROM 
    table1, table2, table3 
WHERE 
    table2.[GUID] = table3.[t2_GUID] 
    AND table2.[col8_bigint] >= table1.[col3] 
    AND table2.[col8_bigint] <= table1.[col4] 
    AND table2.[col9] = 'xyz'                                 
    AND table2.[col10] >= '2022-05-19'
    AND table2.[col10] < '2022-05-20'
GROUP BY 
    table1.[col1], table1.[col2],
    table1.[col3], table1.[col4]
ORDER BY 
    [col1] DESC
```

The statement needs 5 minutes to execute.

Can someone support me where I must add indexes to the tables, so that the statement execution gets a little bit faster?

--- EDIT ---

New style JOIN

```
SELECT 
    table1.[col1],
    table1.[col2],
    table1.[col3],
    table1.[col4], 
    SUM(table3.[col5]), 
    SUM(table3.[col6]), 
    SUM(table3.[col7]) 
FROM 
    table1, table2 
INNER JOIN table3 ON table2.[GUID] = table3.[t2_GUID] 
WHERE     
    AND table2.[col8_bigint] >= table1.[col3] 
    AND table2.[col8_bigint] <= table1.[col4] 
    AND table2.[col9] = 'xyz'                                 
    AND table2.[col10] >= '2022-05-19'
    AND table2.[col10] < '2022-05-20'
GROUP BY 
    table1.[col1], table1.[col2],
    table1.[col3], table1.[col4]
ORDER BY 
    [col1] DESC
```

Comment: Please supply current table *and index* definitions, and also share the query plan via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan. Without this info this question is not answerable. Also knowing how many rows are being joined from each table (number and percentage of table) and how the different `WHERE` clauses affect that would be useful.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Looks like you have a cross join on `table1` as it has no join clause. That would have been noticed with "new" style joins.

Comment: @TheWizard is there a GUID in table1 also? if so u don't seem to be using that in the join..

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, instead of the comma-separated tables from 1989 (the year of the lambada?).

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for pointing that out. Now you now when I did my last SQL query ;-) 

I updated the statement. Would the new statement return the same as the one in old-style SQL?

Comment: @psj01 No, in table1 is no guid. The connection is done via col3 and col4 and col8_bigint in table2

Comment: And `FROM table1, table2` is still old-style.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using table1 as a sort of Limit/Group on table2 - ie. along the lines of "process the rows in table2 between [col3] and [col4]"?

In that case, you might be surprised by SQL Server going the other way: For each row in table2, find me the rows in table 1 that match. You can't index your way out of this.

Your best bet for a quick fix is probably to use new join syntax and then hint at a preferred join order:

```
...
FROM table1
INNER LOOP JOIN table2 ON 
    (table1.[col3] <= table2.[col8_bigint] AND 
     table1.[col4] >= table2.[col8_bigint])
INNER JOIN table3 ON 
    (table2.[GUID] = table3.[t2_GUID])
WHERE     
...
```

This way, you're telling SQL Server to do an index scan on table2 for col8 values between col3 and col4 - for each row in table1. Depending on how many rows are in either table, this could help you out, but you're still in trouble.

What you've done is basically roll your own many-to-many relation between table1 and table2. A better approach would be to use an ACTUAL many-to-many relation and let SQL Server figure things out. The problem with your approach is that SQL Server has 0 chance of estimating the number of rows in table1 that match those of table2 (and vice versa) based on per row values in columns 3 and 4.

With a proper many-to-many relation, your query would look like this:

```
... select ...
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table1_table2 m2m ON (table1.id = m2m.table1_id)
INNER JOIN table2 ON (m2m.table2_id = table2.id)
INNER JOIN table3 ...
```

now SQL Server knows how many rows to expect per row in table1 and table2 and will choose the right plan.

Another thing: table1.[col3] <= table2.[col8_bigint] - if col3 and col4 are not  bigints, which I would suspect from your explictly qualifying col8, the comparison will most likely trigger implicit conversions - those suck big time - mainly because they can force a serial plan in stead of a parallel. If possible, you should convert col3 and col4 to bigints.